# Add a textView behind the gridView?

Tags: android

I want to add a textView at the end of gridView, as http://i3.6.cn/cvbnm/11/41/dd/6307adbd865d210c9e1e7ec9d0933a33.png

I override the getView but there is a textView at the end of every item of gridView, which
i don't like  -- I need the total number of item in the textView as "91 images".

```
<linearlayout>
<gridView>
<textView >
</linearlayout>
```

Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <GridView android:id="@+id/GridView01" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></GridView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Total: 111"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your help,but in your methods the textView is always  fixed at the foot of the screen, i want the textView is at the foot of the gridView as the link  and until the gridView scroll to the end it can appear.